# Angularjs view variable value is not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello, I am new to Angularjs. Below is my code :

**.html file** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="showcase.angularWay.dataChange">
    <head>
        <script src='js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="AngularWayChangeDataCtrl as showCase">
            <input type='text' value="{{showCase.demo}}" />
            {{showCase.demo}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**.js file :**

```
angular.module('showcase.angularWay.dataChange', ['ngResource'])
.controller('AngularWayChangeDataCtrl', AngularWayChangeDataCtrl);

function AngularWayChangeDataCtrl($scope) 
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.demo = "hello";
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXab4.png)

**When I enter any new text in input field then it doesn't update previously present text. (as shown in attached image).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide model

Try like this

```
<input type='text' ng-model="showCase.demo" />
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/kLju9krc/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you very much for your help. I will accept the answer.